# Paperclip generating wrong urls in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using Rails 4.1 and the latest version of Paperclip available. However, paperclip is generating incorrect URLs, missing a part of the route:

```
http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vigme/products/ \
image_s3s//original/35670.0.detail.jpg?1403020602
```

Instead of:

```
http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vigme/products/ \
image_s3s/002/058/083/original/35670.0.detail.jpg
```

My paperclip initializer contains:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The parent object might have an error and doesn't get saved to database, hence the missing `id_partition`

Comment: well i noticed in the rails dev server logs that the correct url is available, and the object was saved to s3:

    '[paperclip] saving /products/image_s3s/002/058/083/original/35670.0.detail.jpg
[AWS S3 200 0.561896 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"vigme",:content_length=>34766,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::HttpUrlProxyAdapter: 35670.0.detail.jpg,:key=>"products/image_s3s/002/058/083/original/35670.0.detail.jpg")'

Comment: did you ever figure this out...i am having a similar issue

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help it's been a while. But try saving the object first, and then calling the url. e.g. post.image = url, then post.save, then call post.image.url